# Using Dream Factory how do I check to see if I am already signed in?

Tags: javascript, api

I am using the javascript code to login and was wondering how I would write this using the window.df.apis library to check the user session still exists.

```
    window.df.apis.user.login({body: body}, function (response) {
        window.authorizations.add("X-DreamFactory-Session-Token", new ApiKeyAuthorization("X-Dreamfactory-Session-Token", response.session_id, 'header'));
        jQuery.mobile.changePage("#index");
    }, function(response){
        $("#login-status").html(window.app.getErrorString(response));
    });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the [example jQuery ToDo app](https://github.com/dreamfactorysoftware/app-todo-jquery) that's provided (this code snippet is from `app.js`):

```
function checkSession() {

$("#loading").show();
// check for existing session, relevant when code is hosted on the dsp
window.df.apis.user.getSession({"body":{}}, function (response) {
    $("#loading").hide();
    // existing session found, assign session token
    // to be used for the session duration
    var session = new ApiKeyAuthorization("X-Dreamfactory-Session-Token",
        response.session_id, 'header');
    window.authorizations.add("X-DreamFactory-Session-Token", session);
    runApp();
}, function (response) {
    $("#loading").hide();
    // no valid session, try to log in
    doLogInDialog();
});
}
```